# Problem with Codestriker. Cannot login/register or anything

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, login, apache-2.2

Is there anyone here has installed and configured Codestriker on Ubuntu? I'm seeking some help.

I've just installed Codestriker on my server Ubuntu 9.x.

I've run the page: http://myserver_address/codestriker/codestriker.pl
on a client machine and got the login page show up.

However, if I try to create a new account, after I put in an email
address and hit register I got the following error:

```
 The webpage at
http://myserver_address/codestriker/codestriker.pl?action=add_new_user
might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
web address.
 Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

If I go back to the create new account page and type in the same email
address I've just used earlier to register it will tell me that:

```
 User account email_address@gmail.com already exists.
```

What did I miss in the configuration? How do I fix it now?

Also, in codestriker.conf, I've specified admin email in
**$admin_users=['email_address@gmail.com']**.
But I don't know where the **password** for this admin account is
specified. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was some setting of compression option in configuration file.
By turning off compression, the problem is solved.

```
  $use_compression = 0;
```